# Cordova on Android - incorrect Activity class?

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova

My Cordova app created using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova won't run in the Android Emulator or on Android because of a ClassNotFoundException. It is unable to instantiate the main activity because it is looking for a class called "my.app.namespace.ProjectName.MyAppName" which does not exist. I have looked in the platforms/android/src folder and the class is actually called MainActivity, so I assume it should be looking for "my.app.namespace.ProjectName.MainActivity." Where is the name of the main activity configured for a VS Taco project? I have searched the whole codebase and haven't been able to find this.

The result on the device is an alert saying "MyAppName has stopped running."

Here's the error from the device monitor:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.app.namespace.ProjectName/my.app.namespace.ProjectName.MyAppName}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.app.namespace.ProjectName.MyAppName" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.app.namespace.ProjectName-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Could you maybe share a demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think this may be caused by copying a pre-existing eclipse cordova project into a new "blank" project created using VS tools for Apache Cordova. I assume the MainActivity.java class was created by the VS Taco project template, and I have since updated the config.xml with my real app name. I manually changed the activity class to the correct name and it works. Should I remove and re-install the android platform?